# Splitting string values in List

Tags: python

I have a huge number of string values in a list like below:

`a = ['1-0.0','1-0.1','4-0.1','4-0.2','4-1.0','4-1.1','4-2.0',...,'23012-11.23']` --> Approx 25000 values

In each value (consider example as '4-0.1'): 4 is x, 0 is y and 1 is z.

I want to analyze this data and get info like below:

```
There are total n values starting with x.
  In which, there are n values with mid-value y and (n1,n2) are the z values.
```

From above example, if we take from '4-0.1':

```
There are total 5 values starting with 4.
  In which, there are 2 values with mid-value 0 and (1,2) are the z values.
  In which, there are 2 values with mid-value 1 and (0,1) are the z values.
  In which, there are 1 values with mid-value 2 and (0) are the z values.
```

Can anyone please let me know if there is any way to slice these values from list in one go and get the data like above?

Answer (score 1):

To split string and get integers:

```
import re

a=["4-1.0", "4-2.0", "4-1.2", "1-1.0"]
b = [[int(x) for x in re.split("-|\.", c)] for c in a]
print(b)
```

Result:

[[4, 1, 0], [4, 2, 0], [4, 1, 2], [1, 1, 0]]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `split()` and `find()`:

```
s="4-1.0"

l = [int(s) for s in (s[:s.find("-")]+"."+s[s.find("-")+1:]).split(".")]
# l=[4,1,0]
```

Do this for each entry in your list `a`. Then I would recommend iterating through that list storing the info in a 2D dict that looks something like:

```
d = { 0 : { 0 : [1,2], 1 : [0,0] .... },
      1 : { 0 : [0,1,0], ...} ,
      .... }
```